# installing and setting-up aws-sdk for ruby rh-ruby22

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-sdk, centos6

i am new to ruby, and i am installing and setting up aws-sdk.

currently ruby -e 'puts $:' command yields following paths:

```
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/rubygems
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/ruby
/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/lib64/ruby
```

and when i install gem install aws-sdk, its not installing to any of the above paths. so, when i use require 'aws-sdk' in my ruby file i am getting error as:

> /opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (LoadError)

my ruby code has following line at the top:

```
#!/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/bin/ruby

require 'aws-sdk'
```

how can i get around this issue, have already spent two days on this.

Answer (score 0):

aws-sdk installation successful when i ran command as:

```
sudo scl enable rh-ruby22 -- gem install aws-sdk
```